# Запуск py файла

Tags: python, windows, консоль, pycharm

Как правильно запустить существующий py. файл через консоль (cmd); ?
Как запустить существующий файл python в PyCharm ?

Comment: в консоли пишите `python main.py`, в pycharm: в меню File->Open... и выбираете ваш файл, или File->New... . Еще, для pycharm попробуйте перетащить тот .py файл и бросить в окно ide

Answer (score 1):

В pycharm: в меню File->Open и выбираете ваш файл, для запуска скрипта перейдите в меню Run -> Run 'File name' или Run...

Comment: Для запуска в pycharm можно еще Ctrl+Shift+F10 использовать